# python3.8 multiprocessing Pool Can't pickle function: attribute lookup getExcelData on __main__ failed when using pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

Trying to read CSV files into pandas data frames using multiprocessing but get pickle error.
python 3.8.8
pandas 1.2.4

```
import os
import pandas as PD
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def getExcelData(fn):
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    return data.append(pd.read_csv(fn), sort=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir = '.'
    fn_ls = [ f'{fn}' for fn in os.listdir(dir) if fn.endswith('test.csv') ]
    startTime = time.time()

    pool = Pool(2)
    pool_data_list = []
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for file_name in fn_ls:
        pool_data_list.append(pool.apply_async(getExcelData, (os.path.join(dir, file_name),)))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for pool_data in pool_data_list:
        data = data.append(pool_data.get())
    res_ls = []
    for pool_data in pool_data_list:
        res_ls = pool_data.get()
    endTime = time.time()
    print(endTime - startTime)
    print(len(data))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/cxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "", line 1, in 
runfile('/Users/cxx/xiaoxi/18_Mercury/raw_data/raw/5000bp/test/test.py', wdir='/Users/cxx/xiaoxi/18_Mercury/raw_data/raw/5000bp/test')
File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "/Users/cxx/xiaoxi/18_Mercury/raw_data/raw/5000bp/test/test.py", line 33, in 
data = data.append(pool_data.get())
File "/Users/cxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
raise self._value
File "/Users/cxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
put(task)
File "/Users/cxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
File "/Users/cxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function getExcelData at 0x7f84e9ad19d0>: attribute lookup getExcelData on **main** failed

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything between `startTime` and `endTime` with a simple map call in a context manager:

```
with Pool(2) as pool: 
    data = [df for df in pool.imap(getExcelData, fn_ls)]
```